# mutool pdf split and order

Tags: pdf

I have a searchable pdf scan of a book that is two book pages per pdf page, flipped counterclockwise. I want to split the pages so that its one page per page.

After reading several other threads here I  used

```
mutool poster - y 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

to split the pages, but now they are disordered. It took the right hand page, which is a higher number page, and put it in front of the lower numbered left hand page. Each subsequent page is disordered in the same way. I tried rotating the pages of the original file 180 degrees and running it again, similar result. Lastly I tried rotating the pages to the correct, upright orientation and running the same command using -x, and that just split each pages in half, and lastly I ran the -y command from the upright orientation and still didn't get what I want.

Clearly I'm doing something very wrong, or not doing something very right.

I've been using Evince Document Viewer for the rotation part.

Comment: What exact commands did you use to rotate it? Either "180 then `-y 2`" or "90 then `-x 2`" should have worked (assuming it's a left-to-right book).

Comment: can you clarify exactly how to use the "180" or "90" part of the command in command context?

Comment: I tried rotating with `mutool draw -R 180` and `... 90`, and some versions crashed, while others inexplicably mirrored all the text.  But maybe that's just my example PDF (a typical exported text document, not a scan).  That's why I asked what command *you* tried.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty frustrating. Double page-layout, rotated documents behave pretty weird using mutool. Don't think it matters much how you rotate them, OP says he used evince, I tried qpdf and mutool . The only way I got rid of the disorder problem was fix the order with `pdftk in.pdf shuffle even odd output out.pdf`.